# Разница в анимации StackPanel

Tags: wpf, анимация, grid, stackpanel

Есть `StackPanel` с другими дочерними `StackPanel`. Все дочерние элементы привязаны к правому краю родительского элемента. Такая конструкция нужна для разделения на слои. Всё упаковано в `Grid` (1 блок ширина/высота) чтобы не делать отрицательные смещения по вертикали для всех панелей. При анимации изменяющей ширину родительской панели последняя появляется как разворачиваемый рулон. Стоит убрать `Grid` и выровнять по высоте все блоки через `Margin`, то панель появляется выезжая с левого края.

Код XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="SliderExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="440" Width="545" Background="Gray">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="200" />
            <RowDefinition Height="200" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="400" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="125" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="400" MaxWidth="400" Height="200" Name="stackSlide1" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="200" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="400" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Width="380" Height="180" Background="#EE000000" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,10,0">
                    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red" Width="380" Height="180">
                        <Label Content="Example #1" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="56" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Width="200" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,30,30">
                    <TextBlock Text="Simple text." Foreground="White" FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Width="380" MaxWidth="400" Height="200" Name="stackSlide2" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <StackPanel Width="380" Height="180" Background="#EE000000" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red" Width="380" Height="180">
                    <Label Content="Example #2" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="56" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Width="200" Height="20" Margin="0,-30,30,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <TextBlock Text="Simple text." Foreground="White" FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Width="70" Height="23" Content="Switch #1" Name="switch1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="switch1_Click" />
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="70" Height="23" Content="Switch #2" Name="switch2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="switch2_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Код CS:

```
namespace SliderExample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static void slidePanelByWidth(StackPanel panel, Boolean hide)
        {
            DoubleAnimation animationSlide = new DoubleAnimation();
            animationSlide.From = hide ? panel.MaxWidth : 0;
            animationSlide.To = hide ? 0 : panel.MaxWidth;
            animationSlide.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
            panel.BeginAnimation(Canvas.WidthProperty, animationSlide);
        }

        private void switch1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            slidePanelByWidth(this.stackSlide1, this.stackSlide1.Width > 0 ? true : false);
        }

        private void switch2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            slidePanelByWidth(this.stackSlide2, this.stackSlide2.Width > 0 ? true : false);
        }
    }
}
```

Вопрос. Как сделать анимацию из `Example #2` в `Example #1`.

P.S. уж очень не хочется использовать `Margin` вида `Margin="0,-458,0,0"`, `Margin="0,-978,0,0"` и т.д.

Спасибо.

Comment: Мало что понятно, вы можете показать код и нарисовать эскиз того, что хотите получить?

Comment: @АндрейNOP изменил вопрос и добавил код. Надеюсь так будет нагляднее разница в анимации с `Grid` структурой внутри анимированой панели и без неё.